# How to Create Custom Shapes in R Highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I am fairly new to highcharts in R, and I am trying to create a similar bullet chart to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/LdHYt/ . The problem I am running into is creating  this function in R:

```
Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.line = function(x, y, width, height) {
return ['M',x ,y + width / 2,'L',x+height,y + width / 2];
};
```

and I'm unsure of where to add this into the code.

I've tried including this code in the hc_plotOptions symbol section, but I haven't had any luck.

Here is the code I tried:

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(highcharter)

    actual <- c(5,10,3,15)
    target <- c(6,7,5,12)
    date <- as.Date(c('2012-02-01','2012-03-01','2012-04-01','2012-05-01'))
    data <- data.frame(actual,target,date)

    highchart(type = "stock") %>% 
      hc_add_series_list(
        data %>% 
          group_by(
            name = "actual",
            type = "column",
            yAxis = 0
          ) %>% 
          do( data = list_parse(data.frame(x = datetime_to_timestamp(.$date), y = .$actual)))
      ) %>% 
      hc_add_series_list(
        data %>% 
          group_by(
            name = "target",
            type = "scatter",
            yAxis = 0
          ) %>% 
          do( data = list_parse(data.frame(x = datetime_to_timestamp(.$date), y = .$target)))
      ) %>% 
      hc_plotOptions(
        scatter = list(
          marker = list(
            # This is where I am inserting the Java Script code from the example
            symbol = JS("function(x, y, width, height) {
                  return ['M',x ,y + width / 2,'L',x+height,y + width / 2];
                  };"),
            # 
            lineWidth = 3,
            radius = 8,
            lineColor = "#000"
          )
        )
      )
```

When I put this code in my graph goes blank, and nothing is displayed. Thank you for looking at this.

Comment: please add your data and packages you used so people can reproduce the problem

Comment: Sorry about that Mike, I just updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R environment doesn't allow to simply wrap Highcharts core functions (at least I don't know a perfect way). The way I do this: I use chart.events.load event to inject JS code (you can't do it in plotOptions marker symbol like you did).
The problem is that **load event** fires **after** the chart is created. So all we need to do is update our markers again after the chart is created so they will be rendered again, but this time using a changed core code.

This is the key part:

```
hc_chart(
    events = list(
      load = JS("function(){
                Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.line = function(x, y, width, height) {
                  return ['M',x ,y + width / 2,'L',x+height,y + width / 2];
                };
                this.series[1].update({marker: {symbol: 'line'}})
      }")
    )
  ) %>%
```

And the whole code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)

actual <- c(5,10,3,15)
target <- c(6,7,5,12)
date <- as.Date(c('2012-02-01','2012-03-01','2012-04-01','2012-05-01'))
data <- data.frame(actual,target,date)

highchart(type = "stock") %>% 
  hc_add_series_list(
    data %>% 
      group_by(
        name = "actual",
        type = "column",
        yAxis = 0
      ) %>% 
      do( data = list_parse(data.frame(x = datetime_to_timestamp(.$date), y = .$actual)))
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_series_list(
    data %>% 
      group_by(
        name = "target",
        type = "scatter",
        yAxis = 0
      ) %>% 
      do( data = list_parse(data.frame(x = datetime_to_timestamp(.$date), y = .$target)))
  ) %>% 
  hc_chart(
    events = list(
      load = JS("function(){
                Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.line = function(x, y, width, height) {
                  return ['M',x ,y + width / 2,'L',x+height,y + width / 2];
                };
                this.series[1].update({marker: {symbol: 'line'}})
      }")
    )
  ) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(
    scatter = list(
      marker = list(
        # This is where I am inserting the Java Script code from the example
        symbol = 'line',
        # 
        lineWidth = 3,
        radius = 8,
        lineColor = "#000"
      )
    )
  )
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update